# Loading a cmd in a console application

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, command-line

I have a console application that executes some commands and outputs some logs.

I need the output that display the command and its result, like this one:

```
>Loading the database...
>mysql -uUser -pPassword myDbName < mydumpFile
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'User'@'localhost' (using password: Y
ES)
>End loading the databse...
```

I did the folowing:

```
void ImportData()
{
    Program.Log("INFO", "Start importing data... <<<");

    Process myProcess = new Process();
    string mySqlArgs = string.Format(" -u{0} -p{1} {2} < \"{3}\"", 
                                      bddUser, bddPassword, databaseName, dumpPath);
    ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = 
                                      new ProcessStartInfo("mysql", mySqlArgs);
    myProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo;
    myProcess.Start();

    StreamReader reader = myProcess.StandardOutput;
    string theOutput = reader.ReadToEnd();
    if (theOutput.Length > 0)
        Program.Log("SQL", theOutput);

    Program.Log("INFO", "END importing data >>>");
}
```

but this code

1) does not display the command itself (just the result)
  2) the request perhaps should be bad formatted, because the result is like a format error in the mysql command

UPDATE: the new code is a litte bit better

```
Program.Log("INFO", "Start importing Materials... <<<".Fill(code));

Process cmd = new Process();

cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

cmd.Start();            

/* execute "mysql -uUser -pPassword base < dump" */
string mySqlCommand = "mysql -u{0} -p{1} {2} < \"{3}\"";
cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(mySqlCommand, bddUser, bddPassword, databaseName, dumpPath);
cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
cmd.StandardInput.Close();

StreamReader reader = cmd.StandardOutput;
string theOutput = reader.ReadToEnd();
if (theOutput.Length > 0)
    Program.Log("SQL", Environment.NewLine + theOutput);

Program.Log("INFO", "END importing Materials >>>".Fill(code));
```

, but anyway, it displays additional information from the cmd.exe first execution (**before** mysql command) and also the command line **after** the mysql command result...

Answer (score 0):

Execute the script as

```
 mysql -vvv -uUser ...
```

this Option will Display the queries during execution of the script.

As for your other Problem: Why do you call a cmd.exe? Just call mysql.exe directly from your program and skip the shell...

Comment: if I call mysql exe directly, I will not see the command itself in the output, isn't it? Like I don't see "cmd.exe" actually...

Comment: I don't need to see the sql commands. I need just as can be seen in the post, the command, and eventually, the error if not OK (for the log).